# What does the String 'ACED00057400' represent?

Tags: java, serializable

In an XML file, I see many elements that have an attribute that starts with `ACED00057400`. What does it mean? How do I parse it? For example I see `ACED00057400095245434F4D4D454E44` and `ACED000574000566616C7365` and want to decode them.

Sample xml in context:

```
.
.
.
<vals>ACED00057400095245434F4D4D454E44</vals>
<vals>ACED000574000566616C7365</vals>
.
.
.
```

Some users might search for ACED0005740 or ACED000574.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ACED00057400` is the hexadecimal encoding of the magic bytes that java serialization uses described in this article: [What Do WebLogic, WebSphere, JBoss, Jenkins, OpenNMS, and Your Application Have in Common? This Vulnerability. By @breenmachine](https://foxglovesecurity.com/2015/11/06/what-do-weblogic-websphere-jboss-jenkins-opennms-and-your-application-have-in-common-this-vulnerability/)

Generally, you can decode this using a hexadecimal to text converter. In the two examples you provided, it would be:

- `ACED00057400095245434F4D4D454E44` to `¬ít   RECOMMEND`
- `ACED000574000566616C7365` to `¬ítfalse`.

Note: the text will not be an accurate conversion of the string because it contains bytes that are not displayed well. For instance `00` in hex is `null` in ASCII.  You can truncate `ACED00057400` and it's a string, then the conversion will be okay.

However, sometimes a java program will serialize an object and it may look like gibberish. In that case, you will need the source code or library of the class that implements [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).